# Read/Write from both files and console windows - C++

Tags: c++, debugging

Today I got a problem when writing program to read both from file and command line.

I use this function to check whether file or not.

```
bool fexists(const char *filename)
{
    ifstream ifile(filename);
    if (ifile.good()) {
        ifile.close();
        return true;
    }
    ifile.close();
    return false;
}
```

Then if it exists, I read some pre-database to program:

```
if (fexists("DOCGIA.TXT")) {
        freopen("DOCGIA.TXT", "r",stdin);
        // read somethings as usual
        fclose(stdin);
        puts(" People Database Loaded!");
    }
    else {
        puts(" People Database Doesn't Exist! \n --> New Database!");
    }
puts(" Press Enter to continue...");
getch();
```

Then I show a menu (in console windows, too):

```
void ShowMenu() {
    int command;
    do {
        system("cls");
        puts("1. st");
        puts("2. nd");
        puts("3. rd. ");
        puts("0. exit!");
        cout << " --- enter command: "; cin >> command;
        if (command == 0) break;
        system("cls");
        switch (command) {
        case 1: func1();
            break;
        case 2: func2();
            break;
        case 3: func3();
            break;
        }
    } while (command != 0);
    puts(" BYE BYE ");
}
```

But when I ran program, it loaded normally (I saw from Console - OK), but Menu is flashing (it appear, disappear, and so on for while - sorry for my bad english), so I can't enter command anymore.

Where is my error in code ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: I don't know why this post is downvote... :(

Comment: Why are you going to mix c++ with the plain c system calls? That's not guaranteed to work well.

Comment: _"I don't know why this post is downvote"_ To avoid the downvotes (1st one was mine) present a [MCVE] in your question please.

Comment: The code in `fexists` doesn't need to close the file. The stream's destructor will do that.

Comment: @PeteBecker I deleted it, and it got same.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ By what judgement can you say that C++ calling c functions does not work very well?  Provided that there is not a conflict in calling convention, C++ can call any function written in C.

Comment: Sorry, my comment wasn't clear enough. That was coding advice, not intended as a solution to this problem.

Comment: @JonTrauntvein _"... that C++ calling c functions does not work very well? "_ I didn't say that. What I meant was I/O operations shouldn't be mixed, which just means the operations aren't synchronized trustfully.

Comment: @PeteBecker btw I also thank for your helpful knowledge :D

Comment: You can condense the entire `fexists` body into the line `return ifstream(filename).good();`.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ synchronisation between stdin and stdout streams is going to depend upon the run time library and the platform.  In my experience, it will exist at the file handle level which sits below iostreams.

Comment: @molbdnilo upd: It doesn't work...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I've synchronized for many times, and it all work correctly. But this is the first time i got stuck like this...

Comment: @LeDuongTuanAnh I spoke too soon, you need `.good()`.

Comment: @molbdnilo I knew that, and it didn't work too...

Comment: @LeDuongTuanAnh That it "didn't work" is unfortunately not any useful information. (It's not supposed to have any effect at all on your whole program's function, if that's what you mean.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> freopen("DOCGIA.TXT", "r",stdin);
> ```

This line closes the old `stdin`, which is the input stream from the console. Since you closed the input stream from the console, it's no surprise that you can't read from the input stream from the console - even if you do it in a different way (through `cin` rather than `stdin`).

Comment: so how can I fix it ? can you help me ?

Comment: @LeDuongTuanAnh Don't use `freopen("DOCGIA.TXT", "r",stdin);`?

Comment: @LeDuongTuanAnh ... using `fopen` and so on, or `ifstream`?

Comment: Ok I used another stream to open file and it worked. thank you

Comment: @LeDuongTuanAnh If you don't mind me asking, why were you using `freopen` in the first place?

Comment: I thought that when I use freopen, it will open file for me to read with "cin", and then I uses fclose(stdin) it will back to console